# Eclipse RCP 4.x: org.eclipse.update.reconcile is set to false on export

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I recently moved from eclipse 3.x to 4.x.

In the properties section of my product file I'm setting the following setting:

```
org.eclipse.update.reconcile = true
```

When exporting the application the config file holds the entry

```
org.eclipse.update.reconcile = false
```

instead.

I tried adding a random property to the config file and it worked, the property got written correctly.

With 3.x this setting was correctly writtem but with 4.x it doesn't work anymore. Any ideas anyone?

It basically looks like the entry is written always and set to false by default. Adding a configuration entry to change it does nothing.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I want my exported RCP application to automatically detect plugins dropped in the plugin folder. I use this mechanism to install language fragment plugins. For this to work I need the org.eclipse.update.configurator plugin to detect new plugins. Setting the flag to true manually in the config file after export works but I need it to work after the export.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking `Generate p2 repository` on the export dialog solves this issue.